# Why my .mdf fil is a lot bigger than the total of UsedSpaceKB of all my table together?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The problem : My database "dm" is very big cause of some table, it's 44Gb. I need to install that db on a very small server so I've decided to remove those big tables (I don't need them to test my dev). After truncating the tables, the size of my database is very strange (see my 3 questions at the end please)

[image: Size of originale DM database]

I've duplicate "dm" in "dm_light" to work on a copy.  I've use this script to identify the biggest tables :

```
SELECT t.NAME AS TableName, s.Name AS SchemaName, p.rows AS RowCounts,
SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB,(SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
GROUP BY t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY UsedSpaceKB DESC
```

[image: Tables of Dm-light before truncate]

I've truncated the 3 biggest tables except "tbl_expedition" (i need this one). According to the previous screenshot, thoses tables are 31Gb, so my db should now size 44 - 31 = 13 Gb

[image: Tables of Dm-light after truncate]

First question : If I select the "used space kb" and make a addition, I find 2294984 Kb so pretty much 2.2 Gb. It's not equal to the 13 Gb I have calculated earlier. Why that ?

Second question : If I looked at my dm_light.mdf file, it's exactly the same size as the original "dm.mdf" : 46Gb ! Why that ?

Third question : If I backup my dm_light db, I find the dm_light.bak file is 6Gb... Why that ?

Thank you for your explanations :)

Comment: You can pre-size a database to any size. Normally, data files are "grown" to a sufficient size so that auto-growth events do not occur. I deleted my answer on this because a proper explanation is beyond the time I have to make an answer. Perhaps you can post this over at dba.stackexchange.com and get a very detailed answer.

Comment: Turn <your favorite search engine> loose on `t sql shrink database`. Files tend to grow over time, but they don't auto-shrink. Deleting (or truncating) data won't make the DB file reorganize itself to remove fragmentation and return disk space.

Comment: This question (and answers) should help: [SQL Server database size didn't decrease after deleting large number of rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28360/7257)